# Sharing data across multiple instances of a java application

Tags: java, shared-memory

Two instances of my java application are deployed in a server. One of the instances will be live at any one point and other will be standby. The live instance will receive some data from some receivers and do some processing. Now if my live instance got shutdown due to some error the standby will become live.

Can the data(map/list) maintained/collected in the first instance be somehow shared to second instance?

Comment: Several ways to share data. Database, a separate server like redis, etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by using some kind of distributed caching mechanism like redis, hazelcast, ignite etc.

You can maintain distributed collections in cache itself. Like [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.org/) provides java like abstractions of collection.

Similarly [Redisson](https://github.com/redisson/redisson) java client(on top of redis) also provides distributed implementation of java collections and much more.